# mov [eax], value - always core dumped

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to edit first letter of char array. 
Don't mind **y** variable for now.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "some_text";
    short int y;

    asm volatile
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"

        "mov eax, %1;"
        "mov byte ptr [eax], 'D';"

        ".att_syntax prefix;"
        : "=r" (y) // %0
        : "r" (s)  // %1
        : "eax"
    ); 

    printf("s = %s, y = %hd\n", s, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile under linux, with following command:

```
gcc -o file file.c -m32
```

Output:

```
(core dumped)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to string literals is undefined behavior in C.

To create a writable string, store it in the stack by using an array instead:

```
char s[] = "some_text";
```

Comment: Some other changes you might consider: 1) If you compile using -masm=intel, you can get rid of the 2 'syntax' lines.  2) You are changing memory, so you should use the "memory" clobber (see the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers).  3) If you change your constraints, you can get rid of the eax clobber, and one of the mov lines: `asm volatile ("mov byte ptr [%1], 'D';" : "=r" (y) : "a" (s) : "memory");`. And if cad's answer helped you solve your problem (even if his syntax isn't quite right), please click the check mark next to his answer so he gets credit.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Dumb me, I knew it looked kinda weird!

Comment: Maybe you have been programming in c# lately?  I believe it does it 'backward' like that.  Anyway, now that it's fixed, hopefully Damian will either give you credit, or tell us why not.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Nope, I guess I was just too tired to notice the mistake.

Comment: Today I found out why `char *s = "some_text";` is write-only. After compilation it appears in code segment instead of data segment. Nobody can touch code segment while app is running.
Thank you both for the answer. Credit is given now.

Comment: @DamianKalinowski Yep. AFAIK, that is to make several same string literals share the same memory, thus reducing memory consumption.